# How to deploy standard Go app on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, gcloud

I created an App Engine project on Google Cloud Platform and followed a very basic [quick start tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go112/quickstart) for Go, but when trying to deploy my app using `gcloud app deploy` it is looking like it's trying to deploy using Docker (flexible environment), whereas I want to deploy using the standard environment. How do I avoid Docker and deploy this app?

```
$ gcloud app deploy
<...>

Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 1 file to Google Cloud Storage                 ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                      
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build ... status: FAILURE.
Error ID: 581A171A.
Error type: BuildError.
Error message: 2019/07/25 23:59:26 Building from Go source in /tmp/staging/srv/gopath/src/<project_name>, with main package at <project_name>
2019/07/25 23:59:26 Building /tmp/staging/srv/gopath/src/<project_name>, saving to /tmp/staging/usr/local/bin/start
2019/07/25 23:59:30 Wrote build output to /builder/outputs/output
2019/07/25 23:59:30 Wrote output to /tmp/staging/usr/local/bin/start
2019/07/25 23:59:30 Making tarball /tmp/tar-out406385400/app.tar.gz
2019/07/25 23:59:31 Creating app image on GCR: <...>
2019/07/25 23:59:32 Failed to create app image on GCR: [/bin/appender.par --src-image us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/go112:go112_20190613_1_12_6_RC00 --tarball /tmp/tar-out406385400/app.tar.gz --dst-image us.gcr.io/<project_name>/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:4d75e939-3879-42b5-8fec-da14ad651baf]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/bin/appender.par/__main__.py", line 90, in <module>
  File "/bin/appender.par/__main__.py", line 79, in main
  File "/bin/appender.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_session_.py", line 71, in __init__
  File "/bin/appender.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_http_.py", line 198, in __init__
  File "/bin/appender.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_http_.py", line 301, in _Refresh
containerregistry.client.v2_2.docker_http_.TokenRefreshException: Bad status during token exchange: 403
{"errors":[{"code":"DENIED","message":"Token exchange failed for project '<project_name>'. Access denied."}]}.
```

Comment: By checking the time you created the case, I can correlated to a Google outage Incident #19009[1]. The incident is marked as resolved now. In the future, if you experience an issue with a Google Cloud Product as in the case of running a quickstart guides, I encourage you to report the issue in the Public Issue Tracker under the right component. Available components can be found in [2]. If the issue still persist, please create a new issue. 
[1] https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/19009
[2] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: make sure your `app.yaml` states that you're using standard environment, something like `runtime: go111`

Comment: @k-f All good, projects deploys this morning. Thanks for the information.

Comment: It's also worth checking the [cloud status page](https://status.cloud.google.com/) for service disruptions - filing issues in disruption conditions isn't very productive.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same error. I tried switching to another language just to make sure the error would still be related to access denied.
My guess was the billing. I have an old account that I have never enabled billing. Neither the free trial $300. In the old times, we were able to register and deploy standard AppEngines without setting up billing.
Once I enable billing (with those $300 free trial ) the deployment succeeded.

Comment: I have a billing account connected with my project. Still it has the same issue. What else could be the problem?